# How to access asp.net page runs on local IIS server through internet

Tags: asp.net

I have a published asp.net web page runs on **local machine IIS server and it is working fine**
How do I access the same web running web site over the LAN and Internet

Additional : I have a **static IP** for the machine and IIS runs on port 8080

Local machine URL for site = localhost/frmHome.aspx
Static IP for the machine = "203.165.24.225" which 80 and 8080 ports are enabled for Http requests

Comment: forward port 80 on your router/switch/hub/whatever else that might need port forwarding to your pc. if you are unable to access your website from the internet, im almost sure you use one of the above.

Comment: It is already enabled

Comment: can you access the website from the same machine using the LAN ip ?

Comment: No that only works in local machine with local IP

Comment: Is there any fine tune to do in IIS????

Comment: you should be able to access your website from the hosting machine using its LAN ip as well. make sure you have the correct path, like `<LAN IP>myWebsite/frmHome.aspx` and not just `<LAN IP>/frmHome.aspx'

Comment: I can access local machine with local machine IP but I cant access from LAN and i try your last method but no result (<192.168.22.130>MyTR/frmHome.aspx) :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are hitting website from your machine then fine it will work with localhost. But when you will hit the same from some other machine over LAN then just replace localhost with your IP. If it is not working then try to ping your IP from that machine to check whether your machine is reachable to that machine over LAN or not.

Comment: he already said that he cannot, and his question is how to do it

Comment: Are you sure that he pinged his machine from other machine connected in LAN? if you are not then let author reply.

Comment: Guys... Ping connectivity working fine but I cant browse my website from other machine...... and is there any firewall setting for port (inbound outbound) need to configure in local machine????

Comment: Perhaps not. You should rebind your application to IIS.

Comment: Guys AmneshGoel and Banana I remove all the IIS setting and newly setup with your guide path. now it is working fine Thanks lot for your support. Last but not least one more thanks to stackoverflow.com team,  God bless you TC